# magento 2 установка через composer

Tags: php, macos, composer, magento

Ставлю на операционной системе macOS High Sierra + использую MAMP Pro. Пытаюсь поставить Magento 2.2.6 через Composer и сразу же сталкиваюсь с проблемой :

```
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.2.6 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.2.6].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.2.6 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
```

Сразу отвечу на возможные комментарии : вот строчки из **php.ini** :

```
    ; Extensions

MAMP_apc_MAMPextension=apcu.so
MAMP_apc_MAMPextension=apc.so
extension=imap.so
extension=gettext.so
extension=mcrypt.so
extension=pgsql.so
extension=pdo_pgsql.so

MAMP_Imagick_MAMPextension=imagick.so
MAMP_Tidy_MAMPextension=tidy.so
MAMP_Oauth_MAMPextension=oauth.so
MAMP_Igbinary_MAMPextension=igbinary.so
MAMP_Memcached_MAMPextension=memcached.so
MAMP_Redis_MAMPextension=redis.so
;extension=uploadprogress.so
;extension=yaml.so
```

Так-же проверил следующие команды :

```
php -m | grep mcrypt
mcrypt
```

Версия php - 7.0.31
Apache - Apache/2.4.33 (Unix)

Answer (score 0):

Для вебсервера и режима cli используются разные конфиги. Загляните в phpinfо() и php -i | grep ini, или попробуйте переустановить php с предустановленным mcrypt

Comment: Я уже решил вопрос, и ваш ответ не помог бы, но спасибо)